# How to use Constants in an if statement in swift?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am learning swift through the official Apple "Learn to Code" and I'm currently on Learn to Code 2. As shown here:

[image: The location of this module is on the last part on Variables]

**My focus isn't solving the puzzle, but rather trying to perfect a part of it**. I'm working on making the character currently go straight when it can't move on the left or the right. Which I know I can this logic operator:

```
if (isBlockedLeft == true && isBlockedRight == true) {
moveForward()
}
```

but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to first declare a constant like this one

```
let Straight = (isBlockedLeft == true && isBlockedRight == true)
```

and simplify the code by including it within an if condition as so:

```
if Straight {
moveForward() 
}
```

However, when I do this, There are problems...

**What should happen:** From the arrow, the character should move four times and stop at the edge because of isBlockedRight becoming false due to the portal next to it.

**What actually happens:** From the arrow, the character moves forward and continues to move forward, even while at the edge.

Below is the full code (non essential parts have been removed for the sake of clarity). Remember that my goal isn't to solve the puzzle, it's to try and get right next to the portal and stop:

```
// Define what "Straight" is 
let Straight = (isBlockedLeft == true && isBlockedRight == true)
let straight = Straight



// Define the function that determines what to do when going "Straight"
func GoStraight() {
    if straight {
        moveForward()
    }
}



//Part that powers the character's movement. Even though it's an infinite loop, the character should still stop as isBlockedRight no longer qualifies as true while at the edge.
while true {
    GoStraight()    
}
```

Comment: surely after each "move" operation you need to re-evaluate the `isBlockedLeft` and `isBlockedRight` conditions and update your `straight` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can you `functions` or `computed properties`

```
var isBlockedLeft = true
var isBlockedRight = true

// computed property
var straight: Bool { isBlockedLeft && isBlockedRight }

print(straight)
isBlockedRight = false
print(straight)
```

Comment: While of course technically correct, applying this in this case will only lead to confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you say that `isStraight` is a constant `bool`, either `true` or `false`, with the value being equal to `isBlockedLeft`'s current value, and `isBlockedRight`'s current value (when isStraight is declared). After that, `isStraight` never changes. But you need it to be a *function* that evaluates to true or false each and every time it is called, using the current values of `isBlockedLeft` etc.

```
func straight() -> Bool {
    return isBlockedLeft && isBlockedRight
}
```

or

```
 var straight: Bool {
    return isBlockedLeft && isBlockedRight
 }
```